# SDK for Hanvon Face id device

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a  [1]: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32811517530.html face id device, i don't have its software development kit and i cannot find that anywhere on the internet. i just have a windows application which has a button for pulling and posting data but i want to start auto pulling auto posting but i cannot do that until i connect to my face id device.
i have no idea how to connect to face id device i just have an internet protocol address because its connected to my network.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to reach out for whatever support documentation the manufacturer has.  There's a product page for the F910 here:

http://faceiduk.com/f910/

I've found a few copies of the user manual online but I don't see any reference to an SDK/API or anything.

https://fccid.io/XQI-FACEID-FX10/Users-Manual/User-Manual-2696823

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1558306/Faceid-F910.html?page=25#manual

Comment: i have seen these manuals but there is no link to get the api/sdk